# How do I connect this database I've created with SQLite 3 to the login system? For example when I enter credentials it should recognize them

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter

```
# PHASE 1 (FILE I/O with One Customer)
# Initialization of Current Balance ** Current Balance is the same for all users for the sake of simplicity ** 
myMoney = open("current_balance.txt")
currentBalance = int(myMoney.readline())

# Imports 
import sqlite3

# Creation of Bank Account and Notifying User(s) of Current Balance
class Bank_Account:
    def __init__(self):
        self.balance= currentBalance
        print("Welcome to Your Bank Account System!")
    # If statements for first screen
    def options_1(self):
        ch = int(input("1. Create an Account\n2. Log into Your Account\nEnter a Choice: "))
        if ch == 1: 
            self.create()
        if ch == 2: 
            self.Log_in()
    def options_2(self): 
        ch= int(input("1. Withdraw Money from Your Account\n2. Deposit Money to Your Account\nEnter a Choice: "))
        if ch == 1: 
            self.withdraw()
        if ch == 2: 
            self.deposit()
    # Function to Create an Account 
    def create(self): 
        user_create = str(input("Enter a Username:"))
        pin_create = int(input("Enter a Pin Number:" ))
        print("Account successfully created!")
     # Function to Log into Account 
    def Log_in(self):
        user = str(input("Enter your username:"))
        pin = int(input("Enter your Pin Number:")) 
        print("Welcome", user, "!")
    # Function to Deposit Money 
    def deposit(self):
        amount=float(input("Enter the amount you want to deposit: "))
        self.balance += amount
        print("Amount Deposited: ",amount)
        print("Net Available Balance=",self.balance)
    # Function to Withdraw Money
    def withdraw(self):
        amount = float(input("Enter the amount you want to withdraw: "))
        if self.balance>=amount:
            self.balance-=amount
            print("You withdrew: ",amount)
            print("Net Available Balance=",self.balance)
        else:
            print("Insufficient balance ")

    def display(self):
        print("Net Available Balance=",self.balance)

# Creating an object of class
self = Bank_Account()
# Calling functions with that class
self.options_1()
self.options_2()
self.create()
self.display()



# PHASE 2 (With Database)

# Define Connection and Cursor 
connection = sqlite3.connect('Bank_Users.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Create Users Table 
command1 = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
bank(pin INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT)"""
cursor.execute(command1)

# Add to Users/Bank
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (7620, 'Kailas Kurup')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (4638, 'Bethany Watkins')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (3482, 'John Hammond')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (3493, 'Melissa Rodriguez')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (9891, 'Gopalakrishnan Nair')")

# Get Results 
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM bank")
results = cursor.fetchall()
print(results)
```

I'm trying to create a bank account management system where the user can create an account, log in, and withdraw/deposit money from that account. After completing the database portion of this project I plan on adding Tkinter GUI.***

QUESTION: How do I connect this database I've created with SQLite 3 to the login system? For example when I enter the username "Kailas Kurup" and the Pin "7620" it should connect to their account as those credentials are in the database I've created.

Comment: you can only check if login, pin exists in database and if not exist then skip rest of code. And if exists then you should use user's ID to access other values in database. But I see you don't use ID in database. And it seem you don't keep information in database but in normal file. And this is big mistake - with SQL you could do many interesting operations. But with text file it would need a lot of Python code.

Comment: if you plan to use GUI then you should separate operations in bank and `input()` - when you use GUI then you will no need `input()`. In `BankAccount` you should have `login(self, user, password)` and in other class you could use `input()` to get values and later run `login(user, password)`